# Chrome Broweser: csi.gstatic.com keeps loading

Tags: google-chrome, google-cdn

I have a website, however when i view the website on Chrome, i see in the lower left corner:

```
Waiting for csi.gstatic.com......
```

This does not go away and stays there the entire time. I am using the google CDN for Jquery etc, however why does this message not go away?

Thanks for every hint!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue: Chrome not loading pages when looking up Google sites. I tried to change the host file but that didn't work. Clearing DNS cache in Chrome didn't work either. Here's what worked for me:

1) go to CMD and type `ipconfig /flushdns`

2) type this in the Chrome address bar `chrome://flags` to reach the flags page

3) look for and disable the `QUIC protocol` flag

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this happens when you are using some google services (e.g. google maps) and you have cookies disabled or blocked.

What I did - I was developing a page with google maps inside it. I accidentally blocked my localhost cookies and then when I refresh this page this gstatic thing was stalling my page (endless page loading).

The solution:

1. Allow all cookies for this page
2. Delete all the cookies for this page
3. Refresh this page

Good luck pal!

Answer (score 0):

Add DNS entry 8.8.8.8 (Google public DNS) on your Server.

See the links below:

http://www.webnots.com/fix-slow-page-loading-waiting-fonts-googleapis-com/ 
http://www.webnots.com/how-to-change-dns-server-ips-in-windows-7-8-and-10/

I was having the same issue while loading the Pins on Google Map. Got resolved by adding the DNS entry.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone working with Angular.

I had a similar issue with angular 4. While hitting the browser with localhost:4200 it shows the message like:

```
Waiting for csi.gstatic.com......
```

When I tried to open chrome developer tool network tab. it was showing like:

[Request to sackjs-node/info?t=1519729418390 was pending](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2BfA.gif)

I have resolved this by removing wildcard routes from child modules of AppModule:

```
            {   
                "path": "**",
                "redirectTo": "home"
            }
```

Answer (score -2):

i had the same problem and i run npm install and it worked.

Comment: It doesn't look like the asker is using `npm`